# why are my variable not adding together in these for statements?

Tags: java

I'm working on some beginning Java logic, and I'm not sure why this is not working.  Here is a method I made:

```
private void printSubclassBoxes(){
        int  coordinateX = ((getWidth() - BOX_WIDTH) /4);

        for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++){

            double coordinateY = (getHeight() / 2);     
            GRect classBox = new GRect (coordinateX, coordinateY, BOX_WIDTH, BOX_HEIGHT);

            GLabel classLabel = new GLabel ("Program");
            double labelCoordinateX = (coordinateX + ((classBox.getWidth() / 2) - (classLabel.getWidth() / 2)));
            double labelCoordinateY = (coordinateY + ((classBox.getHeight() / 2) + (classLabel.getAscent() / 2)));
            add(classBox);
            add(classLabel, labelCoordinateX, labelCoordinateY);
            if (i == 1){
            coordinateX = (((getWidth() - BOX_WIDTH) /4) * 2);
        } 
        if (i == 2){
            coordinateX = (((getWidth() - BOX_WIDTH) /4) * 3);
        } 

        }   

    }
```

Now I'm sure there are probably better ways to do this, but please-I'm not interested in that right now (I'm trying to learn without being spoonfed the answers).  All I am wanting to know is why the ending two if statements are not working like I think they should.

For simplicity sake, let's say

```
100 = ((getWidth() - BOX_WIDTH)

int coordinateX = 25;
```

My understanding is that `int i` gets to that first if statement and adds 25 + 25 so then coordinateX = 50.

then next time in the loop, i = 2 so coordinateX would = 75.

This is what I'm expecting to happen, but it's not.  I seem to be printing the first two boxes directly on top of each other, and then the third is moving 25.

Thanks for your help guys.  Now that I got that loop figured out, I went ahead and solved it a different way.  I ended up assigning coordinateX to another variable and using that to add to the end:

```
int  coordinateX = ((getWidth() - BOX_WIDTH) /4);
        int otherCoordinateX = coordinateX;

        for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++){

            double coordinateY = (getHeight() / 2);     
            GRect classBox = new GRect (coordinateX, coordinateY, BOX_WIDTH, BOX_HEIGHT);

            GLabel classLabel = new GLabel ("Program");
            double labelCoordinateX = (coordinateX + ((classBox.getWidth() / 2) - (classLabel.getWidth() / 2)));
            double labelCoordinateY = (coordinateY + ((classBox.getHeight() / 2) + (classLabel.getAscent() / 2)));
            add(classBox);
            add(classLabel, labelCoordinateX, labelCoordinateY);
            coordinateX = otherCoordinateX + coordinateX;

        }
```

Comment: If you refactor the code, it may be easier to see the issue. You have if statements hardcoded based on the iteration of the loop. Changing these to a more simple form may help your troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the *first* iteration of the loop:

- `i = 0`, and
- `coordinateX = 25`, as expected.

At the end of the iteration `coordinateX` is *not* updated (since `i == 0`).

Then, at the *second* iteration:

- `i = 1`,
- but still `coordinateX = 25` since it wasn't updated.

At the end of the second iteration `coordinateX` *is* updated because of the `if i == 1)` test.

In the *third* iteration

- `i = 2`
- the new value of `coordinateX` is used, which was set at the end of the second iteration.

**Solution**

To not change your code in any essential way, simply replace `if (i == 1)` by `if (i == 0)`, and `if (i == 2)` by `if (i == 1)`.

**EDIT: Lesson**

In the `for(...) { } declaration`, the `i < 3` test is checked at the *beginning* of each iteration, but the `i++` part is called at the *end* of each iteration.

Comment: ah.  I thought i immediately became 1 after being proven to be less than 3...no?

Comment: indeed changing those to 1 == 0 and i == 1 did the trick.  Thank you!

Comment: No problem. In case you do want to improve your program flow, try to get rid of the if (i == ...) statements altogether (hint hint ;) )

Comment: I'm curious about other methods now...I am now adding another way to solve this above, and I'm curious if that is the "best way".

Comment: FYI on the `for(...) { }` declaration: the `i < 3` test is checked at the *beginning* of each iteration, but the `i++` part is called at the *end* of each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You just have an off-by-one loop index problem.  The first time through your loop, `i` is `0`, not `1`.  The second time through, it's `1`, not `2`.  Changing your lines `if (i == 1)` and `if (i == 2)` to `if (i == 0)` and `if (i == 1)`, respectively, will fix your problem.

It's still a weird way to do the loop, though.  A more standard way to do it would be to set up an `incrementX` variable, for example, and then just add it unconditionally each time through the loop.

Comment: I haven't quite figured out how to do that yet as I need to take a value, subtract another value, divide by four and then incriment by that total...

Comment: @Joel, Yeah, so add `int incrementX = coordinateX` before your loop, and replace the `if` stuff with `coordinateX = coordinateX + incrementX`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to increment the value before the "next iteration" you should do it between first/second and second/third but you put update of the variable `coordinateX` at the end of the loop so you should check different indexes: `0` and `1`.

What does it mean?

**This works:**

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
  /* other part of the loop */  
  if (i == 0)
    coordinateX = (((getWidth() - BOX_WIDTH) /4) * 2);
  else if (i == 1)
    coordinateX = (((getWidth() - BOX_WIDTH) /4) * 3);
}
```

**but this works too:**

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
  if (i == 1)
    coordinateX = (((getWidth() - BOX_WIDTH) /4) * 2);
  else if (i == 2)
    coordinateX = (((getWidth() - BOX_WIDTH) /4) * 3);
  /* other part of the loop */  
}
```

Comment: I'm seeing my confusion is simply in when exactly does 'i' change value?

Comment: @Joel, the loop increment `i++` takes place after each time the loop block completes.

Answer (score 0):

May seem like a lame answer but this is what I'd do in these situations.  Put a bunch of print statements in so when it loops you can verify the output you get is what you are expecting.  If it's not at a certain point, start trying to determine why.